# Screen tearing after upgrading monitor

Tags: display, gpu

Today I got an [LG 24MK430H](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-24MK430H-B-led-monitor) and I am experiencing screen tearing when playing videos at 1080p on YouTube. My GPU is an AMD Radeon R7 200 Series (pretty old).

I wanted to know if this could be due to the GPU being old, or if the monitor is not working properly. I don't have other computers or HDMI monitors to try if the error persists with other pieces of hardware. So can the screen tearing happend even if the monitor is fine?

Comment: Look for a setup screen on the monitor to tweak parameters for connecting to the PC.

Comment: You may want to check your cards compatibility with Freesync. If it’s not compatible, you could try disabling Freesync.

Comment: @DrZoo I checked and apparently the GPU is compatible with FreeSync. Would enabling it help with the issue?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik What do you mean by parameters? Sorry, I'm a complete noob in this. What kind of parameters should I look for to try to fix the issue?

Comment: See https://www.lg.com/us/support/product/lg-24MK430H-B.AEU